# Approval Process - Track Submitter of record

Tags: custom-field, approval-process

I am trying to track the 'Submitter' of an Approval process in Salesforce. Although I can who submitted the record when I check the Approval History, I cannot seem to create a field that will contain this data. Is there any way to track this information on a record?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might do is create a custom text field on your object (The one the approval process is on). Then as part of your initial submission actions, do a field update and copy the User Firstname and lastname to that text field.
[image]